# Jquery validation engine, Prompt doesnt appear if called by ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am using callback function in the sign up form to check username validity.
validate[required,funcCall[username_check]]..

Here is the javascript function

```
function username_check(field, rules, i, options) {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    if (username == "" || username.length < 4) {
        return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
    } else {
        jQuery.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('signup/validate');?>",
            data: 'username=' + username,
            cache: false,

            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 1) {
                    return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
                } else {
                    return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertError;
                }
            }
        });
    } 
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signup").validationEngine();
});
```

The alertText is not shown during validation.
if I write the below ifelse condition outside $.ajax prompt can be seen

```
      if (response == 1) {
          return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
      } else {
          return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertError;
      }
```

Is this a bug or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: i think you have error in function. Can u fiddle it? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: No there isn't any error in function (I have double checked )

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am in the same situation...Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using an asynchronous AJAX call as synchronous. The code inside success callback function most likely is not being run, even if it is the result is returned as a result of that AJAX-success-callback function. Validation Engine has specific settings for AJAX validation. See [here](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/using-form-ajax-validation-with-the-jquery-validation-engine-plugin/) or here: [jQuery Validation Engine AJAX Protocol](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#ajax-protocol).